# Custom exception logging in a stateful batch class

Tags: batch

I have developed a batch class which makes callouts to an external system.

```
global class  BatchRunFullOutstandings implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful{
   public String query;
   public String clerkofficecode;
   public list<outstanding__c> newOutstandings = new list<outstanding__c>();

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      query = 'Select id,Name from Clerk_Office__c where Active__c = true';
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){

      try {
        for(sObject so : scope){
            Clerk_Office__c co = (Clerk_Office__c)so;
            list<outstanding__c> clerkoutstandings = new list<outstanding__c>();
            if(co.Name != null){
                String response = CalloutHelperforFetchingOutstanding.createHttpRequest(co.Name); 
                clerkofficecode = co.Name;
                clerkoutstandings = CalloutHelperforFetchingOutstanding.parseXMlStringForOutstanding(response);   
                newOutstandings.addAll(clerkoutstandings);              
            }
        }
      } catch(Exception ex) {
            ExceptionLogging.addException('BatchRunFullOutstandings  job failed for Clerk Office - '+ clerkofficecode, ex);
            ExceptionLogging.saveException();
      }     

      try{
       Insert newOutstandings;
       }

       catch(DMLexception de) {
            ExceptionLogging.addException('BatchRunFullOutstandings', de);
            ExceptionLogging.saveException();

       }
   }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
   }

}
```

I have the following pattern for custom exception logging.

```
public class ExceptionLogging
{
    private static list<Exception_Log__c> listException = new list<Exception_Log__c>();
    public static void addException (String className, Exception ex)
      {
        Exception_Log__c log = new Exception_Log__c(
        Class_Name__c = className,
        Error_Message__c = ex.getMessage(),
        Line_Number__c = ex.getLineNumber(),
        Stack_Trace_String__c = ex.getStackTraceString(),
        Exception_Type__c = ex.getTypeName(),
        Context_User__c = UserInfo.getUserId(),
        Exception_Date_Time__c = System.Now()
        );

        //Don't insert yet just add if there are multiple try catch blocks in a class
       listException.add(log); 
      }

      public static void saveException(){
        Database.insert(listException,false);  
    }
}
```

I want to insert a custom message which tells for which input variable (clerkofficecode) the exception has occurred. That's why these lines -

```
Catch(Exception ex) {
            ExceptionLogging.addException('BatchRunFullOutstandings  job failed for Clerk Office - '+ clerkofficecode, ex);
            ExceptionLogging.saveException();
}
```

I have implemented the Database.Stateful interface but it has resulted in the following DML exception -

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0W2800000C9ScuEAF;
>   first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an
>   insert call: [Id]

When I don't implement Database.Stateful the clerkofficecode is set to NULL during the exception logging.

I would like to 2 understand things -

1) why the variable clerkofficecode is set to null when the `execute` method hasn't finished yet (when the batch doesn't implement stateful)

2) why this wierd DML exception is happening when I implement stateful interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On 1), if your `CalloutHelperforFetchingOutstanding.createHttpRequest` method throws an exception on the first request to it, the assignment to `clerkofficecode` will never happen leaving its value null.

On 2), you are accumulating items in the `listException` list which get assigned Id values when they are inserted and then subsequent calls try to insert them again generating the error. Once items have been inserted, clear the list:

```
public static void saveException(){
    Database.insert(listException,false);  
    listException.clear();
}
```

I can't see why 2) only happens when you implement `Database.Stateful`. As far as I can see you have no need of `Database.Stateful` and the code would be cleaner if the variables `clerkofficecode` and `newOutstandings` were local variables in the `execute` method.

Comment: Facepalm on 1). As far as 2) is concerned I never faced this issue earlier though I'm custom logging on so many classes. But I'll take your point. Can you please advise why local variables are preferred than the class variables? Is it an OOPS thing or specific to Batch Apex ?

Comment: @Bennie Without `Database.Stateful` the variables only have defined values inside the `execute` method so defining them at the class level is misleading to anyone looking at the code.